# REGEXP in java code

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, native-sql

This is the query which is running properly in sql . But when i am ruuning it with java code. Showing query syntax exception

```
SELECT * FROM faq WHERE question REGEXP 'general'
```

My java code

```
 List<Object[]> results = getBaseDao().findByNativeSql(nativeSqlForSearch.toString(), 0,0);
```

where

```
StringBuilder nativeSqlSerach = "Select f from faq f where f.question REGEXP 'general' "
```

Comment: You do not need to call `toString()` on a string.

Comment: What are the two zeros in the `findByNativeSql` call standing for?

Comment: Still i am getting error is REGEXP can be used in java?

Comment: `nativeSqlForSearch.toString()` is not `nativeSqlSerach`, be carefull.

Comment: nativeSqlForSearch is StringBuilder and so i have to convert it to String and i am getting the error is  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REGEXP 'body' ) t'

Comment: @A.J Since you are using a native SQL query anything that works in your SQL client will work the same in Java. For Java that's just a string you are passing.

Comment: Ah, now I see. Why is your `nativeSqlSerach` (note the typo) a string builder anyways? make it a String unless you are using the StringBuilder constructor.

Comment: Please share the error logs.

Answer (score 1):

Some errors I see here.

1. You are using different variables:

   ```
   nativeSqlSerach
   ```

   and

   ```
   nativeSqlForSearch
   ```
2. You are using a String as a StringBuilder object. This is just wrong and I wonder why it doesn't fail to compile. Either use

   ```
   StringBuilder nativeSqlSerach = new StringBuilder("Select f from faq f where f.question REGEXP 'general'");
   ```

   with `toString()` later on, or

   ```
   String nativeSqlSerach = "Select f from faq f where f.question REGEXP 'general'";
   ```

   without `toString()`.
3. I am not sure you have posted a simplified problem or not, but in the case described above you don't need any `REGEX` at all. Just use `=` or `LIKE` wildcard notation.